# Fetch data from a service using python

Tags: python, json

I need to write a python that accesses an internal to organization URL. I have an auth token.

How should my python look

At the moment I have this

```
import json
import requests
from pprint import pprint
path='/Users/Documents/sample_2.dat'
for url in open(path):
   print url[1:-2]
   headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
   response = requests.get(url[1:-2], headers=headers)
   field_value = response.json()
   print field_value["externals"]
```

sample_2.dat has 2 urls 1 below other

Example:

```
"http://xxx.abc.com/mfc/abc/v1/ext_info?id=1841261718,3421035156,B0185LBO7I,B0082SIL3K,B000PS8P3Q,B00G441OMY,0793522048,B00B12D2WY,3637015080,B00TNOUNVU&fields=ex.title,ex.url&fieldgroups=default"
"http://xxx.abc.com/mfc/abc/v1/ext_info?id=0553153617,B003W0CI6Y,B000R08E7Y,B001O2SAAU,B00B1MP3MG,B00QRHJBPU,B00007B4DC,0852597088,B0000003H4,1937715213&fields=ex.title,ex.url&fieldgroups=default"
```

Comment: you mean you don't know how to send the request with `auth token`?

Comment: Yes, am a newbie to python

Comment: read `requests` doc.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this might be useful, which can be found in the documentations

> For GET requests that might require basic authentication, you can
>   include the auth paramter as follows:
>
> `response = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user','pass'))`

As you can see, it is as simple as adding the `auth` parameter inside your get request.